# Remove question mark from url after search submit

Tags: search, htaccess, simple-search, querystring, multiple-sites

I have a multi-language website and my second language goes to a subdirectory `mysite.com/en/` Everything is fine but the search functionality. When I submit my search, it prints a question mark right after the subdirectory like this:

```
mysite.com/en/?/noresult/6bc629a9319d90a1e9703eaf2c00f7cd/
```

And because of it my site redirects to the homepage. I searched and tried many .htaccess codes but it did not work. The URL without question mark works fine. besides i set the "Force URL query strings" to "No" in admin panel but still not working.
Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /en/

  # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*?)/index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

  # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

i don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some .htaccess magic. This should do the trick, but might need tweaking based on your URL needs. Make sure you put this **before** your EE rewrites and index.php redirects.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /en/\?([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /en%2? [L,R,NE]
```

The problem is systemic to something else, so this is probably more of a band aid, but should work for you.

Comment: oh my god, thank you so much, it worked very nice, thank you ;)

Comment: No problem Hossein! Glad to help.